# Поправить регулярку

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Раньше не работал с регулярками, хороший пример чтоб потренироваться и научиться. Есть текст:

```
№   Вопрос  Ответ   
1   Дата звонка     08.08.2014   
2   Время звонка    16:30  
3   Имя оператора   Иванов Иван  
4   Номер телефона абонента     84957777777  
5   Кто звонит   
6   Номер карты  
7   Препарат  
8   Телефон  
9   Комментарий     тест звонок
```

В нём как бы **3 столбца** - **номер**, **характеристика** и **значение**, они разделены табуляцией, но **3 столбца может и не быть, соответственно табуляции перед ним тоже**. Нужна регулярка, которая вытаскивает значения всех этих столбцов.

Есть такой вариант:

```
var TdPattern = new Regex(
            @"^ \s* (\d+) \s* \t ([^\t]+) \t \s* ([^\t]*) \s* $",
            RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Он работает, но выдаёт кривой результат, если после 2 "колонки" не идёт табуляция.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69059/discussion-on-question-by-anatol--).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ответ Андрея](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/747595/182013) — это то решение, которым следует воспользоваться в реальной жизни, когда есть доступ к коду, решить задачу "чисто программным" путём.

Регулярное выражение для нахождения строк в многострочечном тексте (со знаками перехода строки) нужно писать с "якорями" (привязками) `^` (начало строки/позиция после LF, `\n`) и `$` (конец строки / позиция перед LF, `\n`) обязательно с модификатором `RegexOptions.Multiline`. Пробелы между столбцами можно отловить с помощью `\p{Zs}*`, `\p{Zs}` — любой горизонтальный пробел кроме знака табуляции. Если использовать `\s`, то можно нечаянно захватить часть следующей строчки. `\t` найдёт знак табуляции, а значение столбца на одной строке — с помощью `[^\r\n\t]+` / `[^\r\n\t]*`, т.е. 1+/0+ знаков, отличных от CR (ASCII-код 13), LF (ASCII-код 10) и TAB (ASCII-код 9). Чтобы в многострочном режиме (с `RegexOptions.Multiline`) привязка `$` находила конец строки, оканчивающейся на CRLF, необходимо добавить `\r?` перед `$`.

Для объявления необязательной, опциональной, последовательности символов, необходимо использовать подмаски (не- или захватывающие, в зависимости от того, хотим ли мы потом получить все захваченные подстроки или нет) с квантификатором `?`: `(?:...)?`. Т.е. когда в строке может быть, а может и не быть одного столбца, его можно объявить как `(?:\p{Zs}*\t\p{Zs}*[^\r\n\t]+)?`. Так как `?` "жадный", движок предпримет попытку найти последовательность шаблонов в подмаске хотя бы 1 раз. Не найдёт — проверит шаблоны после этой необязательной группы (если есть).

Выражение выглядит следующим образом:

```
(?m)^\p{Zs}*(\d+)\p{Zs}*\t\p{Zs}*([^\r\n\t]+)(?:\t\p{Zs}*([^\r\n\t]*)\p{Zs}*)?\r?$
```

Чтобы не путаться в структуре регулярки, можно объявить две переменные (шаблоны разделителей и столбцов) и использовать их при построении выражения.

[См. демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/Cezqx4):

```
var tekst = "№\tВопрос\tОтвет   \n1 \tДата звонка \t08.08.2014   \n2 \tВремя звонка \t16:30  \n3 \tИмя оператора \tИванов Иван  \n4 \tНомер телефона абонента \t84957777777  \n5 \tКто звонит   \n6 \tНомер карты  \n7 \tПрепарат  \n8 \tТелефон  \n9 \tКомментарий     тест звонок   ";
var s = @"\p{Zs}*";
var z = @"[^\r\n\t]+";
var TdPattern = new Regex(
    $@"^{s}(\d+){s}\t{s}({z})(?:\t{s}({z}){s})?\r?$", // ^\p{Zs}*(\d+)\p{Zs}*\t\p{Zs}*([^\r\n\t]+)(?:\t\p{Zs}*([^\r\n\t]*)\p{Zs}*)?\r?$
    RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline);  
var result = TdPattern.Matches(tekst);
foreach (Match m in result) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);
    if (m.Groups[3].Success) Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[3].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("---------------");
}
```

Результат:

```
1
Дата звонка 
08.08.2014   
---------------
2
Время звонка 
16:30  
---------------
3
Имя оператора 
Иванов Иван  
---------------
4
Номер телефона абонента 
84957777777  
---------------
5
Кто звонит   
---------------
6
Номер карты  
---------------
7
Препарат  
---------------
8
Телефон  
---------------
9
Комментарий 
тест звонок   
---------------
```

Answer (score 5):

Считывайте файл построчно и пользуйтесь обычным `string.Split()`, например:

```
class Data
{
    public string Num { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }

    public static Data Parse(string s)
    {
        var parts = s.Split('\t');
        var data = new Data { Num = parts[0] };
        if (parts.Length > 1) data.Question = parts[1];
        if (parts.Length > 2) data.Answer = parts[2];
        return data;
    }
}
```

Тогда загрузка будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
List<Data> list = File.ReadLines("путь к файлу")
                      .Select(Data.Parse)
                      .ToList();
```

Если данные не в файле, а в строковой переменной, то сплитьте ее сначала по переводам строки:

```
List<Data> list = text.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                      .Select(Data.Parse)
                      .ToList();
```

Символы перевода строки выберите подходящие, может вам достаточно будет просто `'\n'` или `'\r'`

Если могут попадаться пустые строки - можно пропустить их с помощью опции `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

Comment: спасибо, но это не файл, а строка

Comment: @Anatol, добавил

Answer (score 1):

Если столбцы действительно разделены табуляторами, а не пробелами, то поможет следующее регулярное выражение: `^(\d+)\t(.*?)(?:\t(.*))?$`

В случае же, если столбцы разделены несколькими пробелами, то можно попробовать что-то вроде такого: `^(\d+)\s\s+(.*?)(?:\s[^\S\n]+(.*))?$`

Comment: не работает http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: @Anatol http://bit.ly/2iDGPfN

Comment: копипаст из вопроса неправилен, там пробелы для форматирования - по факту их нет, исправил

Comment: @Anatol можете выложить пример правильных данных?